# Limit Page Layouts available to the end user

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am new to powershell and sharepoint.  I am using powershell to create a new site collection.  I have the Publishing site activated.  Once I create the site collection, I want to limit the page layouts the end user can see when they go to the Page Layout section of the site.  I know this can be done from the Site Settings/Page Layout and Site Template Settings and choose the "Pages in this site can only use the following layouts."  I want to be able to set this in powershell as soon as I create the site collection.  I have been reading about GetAvailablePageLayouts.  Is there a property setting I can change like "hidden = true" or something like that to remove the layout from the available choices the end user sees when they try to select the available Page Layouts for the new site.  I guess the bottom line is I want to hide the default page layouts like ArticleRight.aspx and ArticleLeft.aspx and only allow the end user to see page layouts like "MyCustomPageLayout1" and "MyCustomPageLayout2."  Can this be done using only powershell?

Answer (score 1):

Yup. You'll need to use the SharePoint API (objects) in your script, but it is totally do-able. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingweb.setavailablepagelayouts.aspx